How to install macOS Catalina on a 2013 iMac in VirtualBox?
I own a 21.5-inch, late 2013 iMac (with a couple hardware upgrades, namely RAM and hard drive) running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (this is the latest macOS compatible with my specs).
I'd like to run macOS Catalina 10.15.7 inside a virtual machine on my iMac. I'd like to use VirtualBox as the virtual machine because, unlike Parallels VirtualBox is cross-platform and free-of-charge, and unlike VMWare Fusion I am actually able to find VirtualBox online and download it. (Ever since VMWare has been subsumed by Broadcom, it has become very difficult to find a downloadable link to VMWare Fusion.)
As a first step, I followed the link under the Use the App Store title on this page in order to download the official Catalina installer.
Then, thanks to this answer, I ran the script in this project in order to convert Catalina's installation file into a bootable ISO file.
I then followed the instructions under the How to install macOS in VirtualBox heading from this page to set up a virtual machine in my VirtualBox instance (v. 7.0.20).
I used the following configurations: 1) 8192 MB memory size, 2) 64 GB drive size, 3) 2 processors.
I followed all the steps up to and including step 15. I didn't know what do in step 16, and I also was a little apprehensive to follow it, because I didn't understand what it did.
So instead of following step 16, I closed the VirtualBox instance, and then reopened it, and hit the Start button to start the Catalina virtual machine.
The following screen of text messages appeared, and that's it. Nothing more happened.

How can I proceed from here? How can I install macOS Cataline in VirtualBox?
Would it be easier to install it in VMWare Fusion? If so, where can VMWare Fusion be downloaded from?
There is a post similar to this one here, but it's 4.5 years old, and I'm unable to figure out from the answers what I'm supposed to do.

You might need to do the macOS equivalent of step 16.

@nohillside I suspected as much. What would the equivalent look like?

/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage is the path on macOS.

@nohillside I've tried it, and got the following error message: VBoxManage: error: Missing or invalid argument to '--cpuidset'

Which command including arguments did you run?

@nohillside I ran two commands. First I ran cd /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS. Then I ran the following single long command. (I typed the text in the following two cells in the same command line. I split it below in two cells because of stackexchange comment length limitations.) "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" is the name I gave the virtual machine inside VirtualBox.

VBoxManage modifyvm "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbffVBoxManage setextradata "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey"

"ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Catalina 10.15.7" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC"

The formatting in the original article is mixed up. The first command to run would be ./VBoxManage modifyvm "Virtual Machine Name" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff, the next one ./VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3" etc. (replace "Virtual Machine Name" with the name of your VM each time).

Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. I'm not near the computer anymore.

If you Mac can boot Catalina, then you do not need step 16 to run Catalina in a VM.

@DavidAnderson Yes, my mac can boot Catalina: this is my mac's OS. If I do not need step 16 to run Catalina in a VM, then why doesn't Catalina start on my VM?

@DavidAnderson I'll appreciate step-by-step instructions from scratch how to create a Catalina virtual machine in VirtualBox, running on a Catalina host.


Note: Unless you have an internal SSD, I would recommend running your 2013 iMac from an external SSD. Or, add an internal SSD.

I was able to recreate your problem. I was able to fix by uninstalling your version of VirtualBox and installing version 6.1.50 with extension pack.
Your method of installation appears to be unnecessarily complex. I would suggest the following steps.

Downloaded macOS Catalina from the Apple App Store. See here.

Create a USB macOS Catalina installer. See here.

Create a High Sierra virtual machine. Set 4096 MB of memory, 2 processors and 80 GB SATA disk.

Note: When creating the new virtual machine, you will need to select a version. There is no Catalina to select. The newest that can be selected is High Sierra. See the image below. You will be installing Catalina to this new virtual machine.



Add the physical USB macOS Catalina installer to the virtual machine. An image of the settings is shown below.

Unfortunately, the description of my physical 16 GB USB 3.0 flash drive is generic. The brand used to create the image is Micro Center.

Boot the virtual machine from the physical USB macOS Catalina installer and install Catalina. You should first unmount or eject the flash drive volume before starting the virtual machine. Otherwise, you might get the error message shown below.



I did not care for the default screen resolution for my virtual machine. I used the command below to enlarge. My virtual machine is name Catalina. You will need to substitute the name of your virtual machine. You should enter this command while the virtual machine is shutdown.
VBoxManage setextradata "Catalina" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1600x900

Normally, one would install Guest Additions. However, Catalina is not officially supported. Attempting to install Guest Additions will result in failure.
Below is screen shot of the Catalina virtual machine install in a Catalina host.


How I Tested this Answer
My Mac:

iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)
16 GB of memory
macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Booting from external USB Samsung T7 SSD
VirtualBox version 6.1.34 with extension pack installed
VMware Fusion Player version 12.1.2 installed
Second external display is an older iMac connected by Thunderbolt.

Originally, I successfully tested by using VirtualBox 6.1.34. However I wanted to test using newer versions of VirtualBox. I was unwilling to uninstall VirtualBox version 6.1.34. Instead, I first used Fusion Player to create a Catalina virtual machine. Inside this virtual machine, I install VirtualBox version 7.0.20 with extension pack. Using this version of VirtualBox, I encountered the same problem as described in the OP's question. Next, I uninstalled VirtualBox version 7.0.20 and installed VirtualBox version 6.1.50 with extension pack. I was able to successfully use this version to create a Catalina version machine. Below is an image taken from the iMac display.

For a better view, you may want to open the image in a new window. The "Install macOS Catalina" drive shown on the desktop in the image is the USB flash drive plugged into the back of the iMac. This desktop is from a VirtualBox Catalina virtual machine installed in a Fusion Player Catalina virtual machine, which is installed in a 2013 iMac running Catalina.
IMO, Fusion Player is far better than VirtualBox in many aspects. I do not think you can get VMware Fusion Player version 12.1.2 from Broadcom anymore. New versions are not compatible with Catalina hosts.

Thanks. What do you mean by "Created a High Sierra virtual machine"?

Why did you create a High Sierra virtual machine rather than a Catalina virtual machine?

I see. Thanks. And as for steps 4 and 5. How do you add the physical USB macOS Catalina installer to the virtual machine? And how do you then boot  the virtual machine from the physical USB macOS Catalina installer?

I updated my answer to address questions posted in previous comments.
